# $A^x + B^y = C^z$, and NP-completeness

Tags: number-theory, np-complete

I have the equation:

$A^x + B^y = C^z$

$A, B, C$ - constant value, $gcd(A, B) = 1$, $gcd(B, C) = 1$ and $gcd(A, C) = 1$.

$x, y, z \le 2^n$

$x, y, z \ge 3$

$A, B, C, x, y$, and $z$ are positive integers.

For specify the data $(A, B, C, n)$, there is no solution to the above equation?

Problem size is $n$.

Is it possible to prove that this problem is NP-complete?

Comment: ....... No ideas?

Comment: You first? You know, to get something more than the mere statement of a problem?

Comment: I tried to convert it into a special case of quadratic Diophantine equation ($R(a,b,c) \Leftrightarrow \exists X \exists Y :aX^2 + bY - c = 0$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129315/diophantine-equation-and-np-completness. However, it is not so easy (I do not know or even possible). In my question (this question) only exponents can grow exponentially. Unfortunately I can not do anything else.

Comment: If [beal conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture) is true, we can have constant time algorithm for your problem. Sadly, it is open problem. Also see [Fermat-Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture)